# Mapping a symbol-binding macro (in a fn) in Clojure

Tags: clojure, macros

I define a macro to bind a symbol derived from a string to the string like this:

```
lein repl
... Clojure 1.8.0 ...
user=> (defmacro foo [s] `(def ~(symbol s) ~s))
#'user/foo
```

It works as expected when invoked at top level:

```
user=> (foo "asdf")
#'user/asdf
user=> asdf
"asdf"
```

But when I try to map a function that invokes the macro over a sequence, the macro binds the function parameter symbol rather than the one I want:

```
user=> (map (fn [x] (foo x)) ["qwer"])
(#'user/x)
user=> x
"qwer"
user=> qwer
CompilerException ... Unable to resolve symbol: qwer ...
```

The following alternative binds the temporary symbol created by Clojure:

```
user=> (map #(foo %) ["qwer"])
(#'user/p1__1253#)
```

It also doesn't work when wrapped in `doall` as suggested by some of the existing answers I researched on StackOverflow.

How can I define a symbol-binding macro that I can map (in a function or otherwise) over a collection of strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` is a function and `foo` is a macro. Since macro expansion happens at compile time and functions are executed at run time, defining a symbol-binding macro that you can map (and thus expand at run time) is impossible.

What you can do is something like this:

```
(defn foo2 [s]
  `(def ~(symbol s) ~s))

(defmacro foos [ss]
  `(do ~@(map foo2 ss)))

(foos ["asdf" "qwer"])

asdf ;; => "asdf"
qwer ;; => "qwer"
```

Now it's the other way around: the macro is expanded using the functions `map` and `foo`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way of doing it.  The solution first shows how the ***macro*** `foo` works, then uses an intermediate solution with a ***function*** `map-foo-fn` and then `eval`.

The final solution uses a second ***macro*** `map-foo-mcr`. This seems to be needed since `(def ...)` is a special form. This is similar (but not identical) to the problem of "turtles all the way down" where using a macro in one place requires all callers to also be macros, not functions.

```
(ns clj.core
  (:require
    [tupelo.core      :as t]  ))
(t/refer-tupelo)

(defmacro foo 
  [arg]
  `(def ~(symbol arg) ~arg))

(foo "aa")
(spyx aa)

(defn map-foo-fn
  [coll]
  (cons 'do
    (forv [elem coll]
      (list 'foo elem))))
(newline)
(prn  (map-foo-fn ["bb"] ))
(eval (map-foo-fn ["bb"] ))
(spyx bb)

(defmacro map-foo-mcr
  [coll]
  `(do
     ~@(forv [elem coll]
        (list 'foo elem))))
(newline)
(println (macroexpand-1 '(map-foo-mcr ["cc" "dd"] )))
(map-foo-mcr ["cc" "dd"] )
(spyx cc)
(spyx dd)
```

Results:

```
aa => "aa"

(do (foo "bb"))
bb => "bb"

(do (foo cc) (foo dd))
cc => "cc"
dd => "dd"
```

Remember that, while macros ***can*** do one thing that functions can't (avoid arg evaluation), macros ***cannot*** do other things that functions can. In particular, macros can't be passed to `map` *et al* where higher-order-function argument is required.

For more details see http://www.braveclojure.com/writing-macros  and search for "Macros All the Way Down"

Note that `project.clj` needs

```
:dependencies [
    [tupelo "0.9.13"]
```

for `spyx` to work